# Processing Power - Mobile Devices vs Desktop - 100x difference?

Tags: java, android, computation

Has anyone compared the processing power of mobile devices with PC? I have a very simple matrix work. Coded in Java, it takes ~115ms for my old PC to finish the work. THE VERY VERY SAME FUNCTION takes 17000 ms. I was very shocked. I didn't expect that the tablet would be close to PC - but I didn't expect it is ~150x slower either!!

Has anyone had a similar experience? Any suggestion? Does it help if I write the code in C and use Android NDK?

The benchmark code in Java:

```
package mainpackage;

import java.util.Date;



public class mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Date startD  = new Date();
        double[][] testOut;
        double[] v = {1,0,0};
        double t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            t=Math.random();
            testOut=rot_mat(v, t);
        }
        Date endD  = new Date();
        System.out.println("Time Taken ms: "+(-startD.getTime()+endD.getTime()));


    }

    public static double[][] rot_mat(double v[], double t)
    {
           double absolute;
           double x[] = new double[3];
           double temp[][] =  new double[3][3];
           double temp_2[][] =  new double[3][3];
           double sum;
           int i;
           int k;
           int j;

           // Normalize the v matrix into k
           absolute = abs_val_vec(v);
           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               x[i] = v[i] / absolute;
           }


           // Create 3x3 matrix kx
           double kx[][] = {{0, -x[2], x[1]}, 
                              {x[2], 0, -x[0]},
                              {-x[1], x[0], 0}};
           // Calculate output
           // Calculate third term in output
           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               {
                   sum = 0;
                   for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                   {
                       sum = sum + kx[i][k] * kx[k][j];
                   }
                   temp[i][j] = (1-Math.cos(t))*sum;
               }
           }
           // Calculate second term in output
           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
               {
                   temp_2[i][k] = Math.sin(t)*kx[i][k];
               }
           }


           // Calculate output
           double[][] resOut = new double[3][3];
           for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
               {
                   resOut[i][k] = temp_2[i][k] + temp[i][k] + ((i==k)?1:0);
               }
           }
        return resOut;

    }



    private static double abs_val_vec (double v[])
    {
           double output;

           output = Math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2]);

           return output;
    }


}
```

Comment: Firstly, I wouldn't use `Date` to do any kind of benchmarking...

Comment: Factor the library calls out. You don't want to benchmark `random`, or trig functions.

Comment: @Tyler and Michael, I removed the trig function and random, I also changed the Date to System.currentTimeMillis(). But it is still 45x slower. Having said that, I am not sure if I understand why you said I cannot use trig functions? Don't Android and Java use the same algorithm for Math.sin?

Comment: If you're doing this with the debugger attached, then detach it - you'll see a significant speed increase.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestion?

Micro-benchmarks only measure the performance of the micro-benchmark. And, the only decent way to interpret micro-benchmarks is with micro-measurements. Hence, savvy programmers would use tools like Traceview to get a better sense of where their time is being taken.

I suspect that if you ran this through Traceview, and looked at LogCat, you would find that your time is being spent in two areas:

1. **Memory allocation and garbage collection**. Your micro-benchmark is chewing through ~3MB of heap space. In production code, you'd never do that, at least if you wanted to keep your job.
2. **Floating-point operations**. Depending upon your tablet, you may not have a floating-point co-processor, and doing floating-point math on the CPU sans a floating-point co-processor is very very slow.

> Does it help if I write the code in C and use Android NDK?

Well, until you profile the code under Traceview, that will be difficult to answer. For example, if the time is mostly spent in `sqrt()`, `cos()`, and `sin()`, that already *is* native code, and you won't get much faster.

More importantly, even if this micro-benchmark might improve with native code, all that does is demonstrate that this micro-benchmark might improve with native code. For example, a C translation of this might be faster due to manual heap management (`malloc()` and `free()`) rather than garbage collection. But that is more an indictment of how poorly the micro-benchmark was written than it is a statement about how much faster C will be, as production Java code would be optimized better than this.

Beyond learning how to use Traceview, I suggest:

- Reading [the NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), as it includes information about when native code may make sense.
- Reading up on [Renderscript Compute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html). On some devices, using Renderscript Compute can offload integer math onto the GPU, for a massive performance boost. That would not help your floating-point micro-benchmark, but for other matrix calculations (e.g., image processing), Renderscript Compute may be well worth researching.

Comment: Thanks for your note. Just a quick side note, after profiling I got ~20% in trig functions, 60% "self" which I believe it means the simple multiplications that I have...

Comment: @Kasra: If I am interpreting your "self" reference correctly, then that will be memory allocations and inline operations like your floating-point multiplications. The time that is "stolen" from the micro-benchmark for garbage collection should show up as pauses in Traceview, where nothing seems to be going on. This assumes a single-core CPU; if you are using multiple cores, then GC might run on another core and there would be limited impact on performance.

Comment: @Kasra: Note that, in theory, the JIT compiler should be converting your micro-benchmark into native instructions. I don't know of a good way to confirm that. You may wish to do some research on what CPU is in your tablet. If it is ARMv7, it will have a floating-point co-processor. If it is ARMv5, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

Processing power alone is not everything when you compare very different architectures. In fact, you're very likely not benchmarking the computing architectures alone.

A key factor in benchmarking. *When you're dealing with something that takes a lot of variables into account, **isolate the one you want to test, and keep others constant and preferably equal.***

In your situation, some examples for variables that affect your result:

- the actual computing architecture, which is a complex set of variables itself (processor design and implementation, memory hierarchy etc)
- the OS
- the different *Java Virtual Machine* implementation for the different variables above
- the additional layers the Dalvik implies

Answer (score 0):

There are at least eight sets of comparisons between PCs and Android devices for my numerous Android benchmarks in the following. Below are results from my Linpack benchmark (including Java) that show the Androids in a better light than your results. Other results (like Dhrystone) show that, on a per MHz basis, ARM’s CPUs can match Intel’s.

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm

```
 Linpack Benchmark Results

 System   ARM    MHz   Android  Linpackv5  Linpackv7  LinpackSP NEONLinpack LinpackJava
 See                              MFLOPS     MFLOPS     MFLOPS     MFLOPS     MFLOPS

  T1    926EJ    800       2.2      5.63       5.67       9.61       N/A        2.33
  P4    v7-A8    800     2.3.5                80.18                            28.34 @G
  T2    v7-A9    800     2.3.4     10.56     101.39     129.05     255.77      33.36
  P5    v7-A9   1500     4.0.3               171.39                            50.87 @G
  T4    v7-A9   1500a    4.0.3     16.86     155.52     204.61     382.46      56.89
  T6    v7-A9   1600     4.0.3               196.47
  T7    v7-A9   1300a    4.1.2     17.08     151.05     201.30     376.00      56.44
  T9    926EJ    800       2.2      5.66
  T11   v7-A15  2000b    4.2.2     28.82     459.17     803.04    1334.90     143.06
  T12   v7-A9   1600     4.1.2               147.07
  T14   v7-A9   1500     4.0.4               180.95

  P11   v7-A9   1400     4.0.4     19.89     184.44     235.54     454.21      56.99
  P10   QU-S4   1500     4.0.3               254.90

 Measured MHz a=1200, b=1700 


         Atom   1666     Linux               204.09     215.73                117.81
         Atom   1666   Windows               183.22                           118.70
         Atom   1666   And x86                                                 15.65
        Core 2  2400     Linux              1288.00                           901.00
        Core 2  2400   Windows              1315.29                           551.00
        Core 2  2400   And x86                                                 53.27

 System - T = Tablet, P = Phone, @G = GreenComputing, QU = Qualcomm CPU
 And 86 = Android x86
```

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question, but may I ask you what the unit of the numbers listed under Linpack are? Does this mean that the lower the number is the faster the computation will be? Or the other way?

Comment: MFLOPS is Millions of Floating Point Operations Per Second - the standard performance measure for floating point calculations - high is best, of course.